# Nautilus script to compare hash values of two files

Tags: bash, checksums, hash

Sometimes I need to check if two files are identical. I attempted to make a bash script to achieve that but I can not make my head around it.

I found below script on the net, I placed it in Nautilus scripts folder when I right click on a file and call script from right click context menu it prints the checksum of file. How can I improve it to take the second file and tell if they are identical?

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
zenity --info --text "$(md5sum $1 | sed 's/ /\n/')"
```

Comment: Want to compare the two files by their md5sum?

Comment: @A.B. yes, I want to check if they are identical or not only.

Comment: What's your Nautilus version?

Comment: @A.B.  it's 3.10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'

for file in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do
    result="${result}"$(md5sum "${file}")"\n"
done

zenity --info --text="${result}"
```

I learned from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto that Nautilus puts the list of selected files in that NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS variable. They're separated by newlines. So I set the IFS variable to "newline" so a "for" cycle iterates on lines, not whitespace-delimited words as is the default. For each line/file, I run md5sum on it and append the result to a variable. Finally the variable is output using zenity as you originally did.

This will simply show the md5sum for any selected files (it works for more than 2 files too), so you can visually determine if they're the same. You can obviously modify this script to your needs:

- Maybe just exit if more than 2 files were selected
- Do the md5 comparison in the script and just output "identical / different" based on the result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That Nautilus variable surely allows what I want.